# PS Script fails only when invoked by Run with PowerShell. CmdletBinding is the root cause

Tags: powershell

When I run PS script with right click > "Run with PowerShell", fails with unknown error which is related to cmdletbinding attributes. This is a fragment with some default values of switches if they are not specified by user:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$false)][string]
[Alias("Computers")]$File = "servers.txt",
[Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true, Mandatory=$false)][int]$p = 1
)
```

And this is the error message.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfEvw.png)

If I invoke the script from a new PS window it runs fine. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's because cmdletbinding? Maybe it's because different ErrorActionPreference that are set in a console but not when you "run with ..."?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. When I delete the whole part related to cmdletbinding the script runs fine. This error occurs on some workstations, there is no pattern depending on OS or PS version. Sometimes fails on 2012 R2 with PS v4, pass fine on 2008 with PS v2 and vice versa.

Comment: i reproduced code (the part) and no issues at all - im 100% it comes with some variable or function look at the error details ParentContains...
plus i do not see any reason using this  in ps file. it's helpful inside of the function but here if understand this is only inline script in one file...